# Twilio SMS Environment(s)

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api

I am setting up SMS with Twilio in a project and have come to somewhat of a crossroad. Currently I am in the development stage and found myself wondering, should I have a Twilio phone number for each of my environments (dev, stage, prod)?

Seems like if I want to track usage and get accurate data, then separate numbers could be needed, but it also feels somewhat redundant to have 3.

Is there a way to use 1 phone number for multiple environments or must I buy 3 to achieve accurate usage statistics?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to differentiate traffic on a phone number into different environments. If you want to separate the usage of your numbers, then I would recommend a different number per environment. And further, a different [subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/blog/guide-twilio-subaccounts) per environment too.